# Camara App crashes on click

Tags: android

I am doing a camara project where the captured image on one activity is sent to another activity. The issue is when i click on the capture button the app crashes and shows null point exception on the logcat

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();



        // Create the Camera preview view
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        final Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EditActivity.EXTRA_BYTES, data);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        // Add a listener to the capture button
        ImageButton captureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cam));
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }

        );


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
        mPreview.stopPreview();
    }

    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     *
     * Returns null if camera is unavailable.
     */
    private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist). Do nothing.
        }
        return c;
    }

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        private void stopPreview() {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // Stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                // Tried to stop a non-existent preview. Do nothing.
            }

            // Set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

            // Start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace and exact exception

Comment: "_and shows null point exception on the logcat_" When asking a question here, it would be a good idea to _actually show us_ that LogCat and the Stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you chose a low resolution for the image, you are crashing with a transaction-too-large exception. There is a 1MB limit on the size of an IPC transaction, which translates to a ~1MB limit on the size of your `Intent`. Most camera photos will be far larger than that.

Your options are:

1. Take low-resolution images
2. Get rid of the second activity and do all of this work in one activity (e.g., using multiple fragments)
3. **Carefully** get the image from the first to the second activity by some other means (e.g., singleton), taking appropriate steps to avoid nasty memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

This is the part where your code crashes:

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                }
```

Let's see where can it come from. You have four values:

- `mCamera`: if `mCamera` is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown, since you try to use the `takePicture` method of an unexisting object
- the first and second parameter is `null`. If `takePicture` tries to use data members or methods of those parameters, then `NullPointerException` is thrown
- `mPicture` might be `null`. If `mPicture` is `null` and you try to use one of its data members/methods inside `takePicture`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown

I believe `mCamera` is `null`. If I am right, you should review how you create your camera object:

```
/**
 * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
 *
 * Returns null if camera is unavailable.
 */
private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist). Do nothing.
    }
    return c;
}
```

Here, you hide any `Exception`. I would like to kindly ask you to debug your project and see whether an `Exception` is catched here. If you see the given `Exception`, you will most probably realize what your problem is.

Comment: yeah exactly the app crashes there. what is the solution?

Comment: @Yash, the solution is to find out what causes the NullPointerException. Is mCamera null at the moment of execution? If so, find out what the nature of ignore (the Exception you ignore is)